# Web Service or Jms

Tags: java, web-services, asp-classic, jms

Currently I am responsible for a service:
To make a Http Get call on remote server to recharge the mobile which uses asp (plain asp without .net). URL looks like recharge.asp?param=provide Ai amount 100 Num 9999999
Server takes about 10 sec to recharge the mobile and then send the response.
Since the client application uses Java EE technology what is best suited Java EE technology for this scenario (Web service, JMS etc  )? What about synchronous and asynchronous request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since two different technologies are concerned I would suggest going for webservice, as it uses industry standards and not Java standards,

Since this is transactional in nature, message should be synchronous, as users in general are more convenient waiting rather than being notified later about success or failure, had the wait period long then it could have been a different story, but in general 10 seconds is acceptable.

If your capacity planning suggests that 10 seconds wait will put server under extreme load, please take asynchronous approach while ensuring that user is notified about success or failure.

[WS Architecture](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/webservices/using/webservbp3.html)

[Transaction In WS](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-transws/)

Comment: thanks mprabhat. yes this is transactional. But how to manage transactional and synchronous behavior using web service?

Comment: For synchronous webservice you can use RPC style, and transaction uses two pieces WS Coordination and WS Transaction, WS coordination is the ability to move message between two interacting parties and ws-transaction is used to keep the ACID properties intact.